# What reputation do you need on Stack Overflow to receive an invite to Careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, jobs

What reputation do you need to have on Stack Overflow to receive an invite to Careers?

The site says "Stack Overflow grants new invites to users fitting certain criteria of activity on Stack Exchange sites, including reputation".

Comment: I also, at some point, got the impression that some users are able to sign in and use the service without an invitation as long as they used their same openid, meaning that an invitation code may not be required if you meet the minimum reputation built into the site.  Can't find any good references for either impression, though.

Comment: @Pollyanna sort of...you'll still get an invite, but if you have a profile on Careers we'll attach it to that so you can just go to the site and click "create" -- but you have to receive an invite first.

Comment: Personally I think simple request is not enough to understand how much the person might need an invite to careers. Unfortunately no one cares.

Comment: Let's say that it doesn't matter so much, now even people with small reputation (<1000) are getting the invites but the success ratio is small because if you do not have at least 5000k, you may be afraid of showing your questions. I found this from friends that are very good profesionals, but that did not invest too much time on the SO-game :)

Comment: Is just StackOverlow used for rating or are other sites from network used?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a secret :)

The exact criteria probably won't be announced, because we don't want people to game it.  It's not a straight "greater than X reputation", but based on expertise in a tag, and your recent activity on the site.

Also, we're trickling them out slowly (rather than blasting out 25,000 invites in the first week), so if you haven't gotten an invite yet it doesn't mean you won't.

There are other ways to get an invite, too:  You can request an invite at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one or you can make friends with somebody who is already in the system and has some invites to give out.

Comment: Hey David, wanna be friends?

Comment: If you request an invite and do not receive a reply by email, does that mean the request was rejected?

Comment: @Andomar no, it means you're on the list but we haven't gotten to you yet.

Comment: @David, the provided link is redirecting to [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/editinline).  Is there still a chance to ask for a invite or to become your friend nowadays? :D

Comment: @jachguate Not sure I understand.  If you already have a profile, you don't need to be invited.  Are you looking for invites to give out to others?

Comment: @David, I did have a profile but I did not find the option to turn me as an active job seeker until minutes after my comment here, so I think this is all about, right?.  For now, I'm just interested in a couple of invitations to give to others...

Comment: @David: If you request an invite and don't get a reply for two months does it mean the request was rejected? Do you get informed if the request is rejected? I feel like I'm in the dark with this system...

Comment: So I had a profile in Careers 1.0, and that seemed to carry into 2.0, is that a fluke? (i.e. I wasn't invited to Careers 2.0, but I have a 2.0 profile, and was granted invites to give away)

Comment: @Mark Most Careers 1.0 users were grandfathered in (anybody who actually filled out a profile).  We figure that most of those early adopters were self-selecting people who learned about Careers from following the podcast, the blog, etc.

Comment: It would be good to know at least where you are "in the queue", there's not even a confirmation whether the request was received - does it take months to get invited at this point? (That's my impression at least)

Comment: I wish I could `-1` this. Keeping the algorithm secret is just `WRONG` (like with credit scores). And for thousands of reasons. There are good explanations on Area51 describing how the proposal progress is calculated, why not doing the same? Do people game/cheat there? If the invitation system for Career 2.0 let people cheat, then it needs to be revised. Making it public might be the best solution to have a fair and robust invitation algorithm. Take the ELO Rating System (chess) for instance. It's public, how many GrandMasters do you think earned their title gaming/cheating the rating system?

Answer (score 3):

On [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq) it says *under FAQ For Programmers*

> How do I get a Careers 2.0 Profile?
>
> Careers 2.0 profiles are by invitation
> only. You may be invited based on your
> participation on Stack Overflow, or by
> another programmer who admires your
> work.

On the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/) it says

> **1. It’s free (to job seekers)… but invite-only.**
>
> We used to charge job seekers $19 to
> post resumes. That was supposed to be
> a basic sanity filter, to make sure
> that everyone in our system was really
> looking for a job.
>
> You didn’t like that, and we had to
> agree. There are better filters than
> money. Starting today, posting a
> profile on Careers 2.0 is 100% free,
> but you have to be invited.
>
> Invitations come from your peers.
> We’ll give members a few invites to
> distribute to programmers they know
> and trust. Or, contribute to Stack
> Overflow (and our other sites), get
> voted up by a lot of smart people, and
> you may get an automatic invite.
>
> By the way, if you paid in the past:
> thank you! Your account is free for
> life. But if you don’t think it was
> worth it, just email us for a full
> refund.

Comment: That answer says nothing about reputation...

Comment: Hmmm. I have a decent amount of reputation, and I paid for careers back in the day, but I still can't create a profile on Careers 2.0 :)

Comment: @Andomar if you ever paid for Careers you should already have a profile.  I found a user in Careers with your creds, but I don't see any record of a purchase for that user.  Could you email careers@stackoverflow.com with more info so we can figure out what happened?

Comment: @David Fullerton: Looks like I paid using a different OpenID.  If I use that OpenID, FireFox gives an error "infinite redirect".  That's OK, I am just interested to know whether my SO account qualifies.

Comment: Yup, so where's the refund button? :)

Answer (score 1):

The site is now updated with this

> To make sure we only have great programmers, Careers 2.0 profiles are invitation-only. You can earn invitations for friends and colleagues when you:
>
> Tell us more about yourself
>
> Try out some of the features on your profile. Get to 150 completeness, and we’ll grant you a batch of invites.