# How long does it take to get response from Careers on SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, jobs, review, invitation

I have tried to create my profile on Careers, but being an invitation-based system and having no one around I could get invitation from, I tried my luck posting my address at the details pane - the one which says

> No doubt! You can request an invitation by entering your email address below, and we will review it.

How long does this review process take and will I even get a response in the case I'm not accepted? I know I'm a little bit impatient here, but after 2 weeks of waiting, I'm not sure anymore whether I should keep waiting or simply give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still early on in the process, so we are still learning and tweaking the system as we move along and for the most part are still trickling out the Stack Overflow *House* invites. Therefore, the backlog for requests is still increasing at this point.

However, as David Fullerton pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81528/what-reputation-do-you-need-on-stack-overflow-to-receive-an-invite-to-careers/81703#81703), there is another way to get invites and that is to find somebody else already in the system with a profile, has invites, and have them invite you. (Twitter, the SO chat rooms, etc). If you can't get one that way, and you are **actively** looking for a job, emailing Careers customer support with your story and a link to your Stack Overflow profile showing that you are in fact a programmer, I'm sure somebody on the team will invite you.

Comment: If it's been a few weeks, though, you probably want to send out a "Thanks for your interest / sorry about the delay!" email to everyone in the queue then suggesting they track could down someone with invites too. (I'd say link them here but then everyone will just email the team as you've suggested.)