# What are the requirements to get auto-invited to have a profile on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What reputation do you need on Stack Overflow to receive an invite to Careers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81528/what-reputation-do-you-need-on-stack-overflow-to-receive-an-invite-to-careers)

Upon going to "My Profile" on the Careers page, the text includes:

> Stack Overflow profiles are invitation-only, either by us or by your peers. If you haven't been invited, ask among your friends and colleagues.
>   Stack Overflow grants new invites to users fitting certain criteria of activity on Stack Exchange sites, including reputation. Participate more, ask good questions, and give good answers. You never know what might appear in your inbox.

Fair enough, but I'm surprised I have not seen anyone ask: What specifically are the requirements for these "certain criteria of activity?"  Or is that some closely-guarded secret held by some secret society, with only four people knowing the answer?