# Minimum requirements Careers 2.0

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions, jobs

I'd like to know what are **minimum requirements** to access on Careers 2.0 depending on the account access?

Those requirements are assessed only on the first submission or even if evaluate according **time to time**.

Comment: [It's a secret](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81528/what-reputation-do-you-need-on-stack-overflow-to-receive-an-invite-to-careers/81703#81703).

Comment: why should it be?

Comment: According to the linked post, it is to avoid users gaming the system. However, that post is from a long time ago. Perhaps things have changed since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, there are three ways to get a Careers profile.

1. Wait for an invite. Invitation is based on your participation on Stack Overflow. The actual criteria for issuing invites [appear to be secret](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81528/what-reputation-do-you-need-on-stack-overflow-to-receive-an-invite-to-careers/81703#81703) to avoid users gaming the system.
2. Get an invite from someone who has already has an account<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>.
3. Be involved in Open Source code development. If you have a GitHub or CodePlex account, [you can try getting a Careers account on the back of your involvement there](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one). Again, I believe the criteria is not disclosed.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Yes, I have invitations to spare, but I generally offer then only to those I know personally and can vouch for or those whose work I am aware of.</sup>

Comment: I have i project on GitHub but my invitation it's already pending...it's updated?

Comment: I don't know that criteria they use to judge a GitHub account, but merely having a project may not be enough. I believe the system also take into account how active the project is, the number of followers/contributors, etc.