# Where's my career's canonical url?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I've two questions.

### First Question

I found careers ad and immediately applied for it when I was < 3000 reps because I thought it would be fun if I got accepted :)

After few days, I got reply from SE with an invitation, which I gladly accepted.

So, is there any prerequisites before getting invitation or everyone who applies gets it?

<sub>The above happened very long back</sub>

### Second Question

What is the url of my careers profile? I'm not able to find it. I see many profiles who sport their careers urls. But where's mine?

Answer (score 6):

The exact reputation you need on Stack Overflow to get an invite to Careers [is apparently a secret](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81528/what-reputation-do-you-need-on-stack-overflow-to-receive-an-invite-to-careers). Your activity on the site and tag scores was apparently good enough to earn you a spot.

The "vanity" URL for your Careers page is something you have to set up. To do so:

1. Log into your Careers account at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/.
2. Click on "my profile" (the orange button at the top of the page).
3. Click on "edit profile" (the link in the light orange box at the right).
4. Click on the top-most "edit" link, next to your profile picture.
5. Type whatever you want into the "Custom Profile URL" box.
   For example, if you enter `amitjoki`, you'll have a custom Careers URL like: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/amitjoki
6. Oh yeah, and then you have to hit the big orange "Save" button. Obviously.

   [image]

Comment: I've just done what you've said. I entered `AmitJoki` but this http://careers.stackoverflow.com/AmitJoki gives a 404

Comment: Huh, I don't know then. It worked for me. It might be a caching problem. (I forgot to say you have to click the big orange "Save" button. I'm sure you did that, though.)

Comment: @AmitJoki your privacy settings must be Public, by default it's private. There is a "privacy settings" link in the right side bar of your profile, click it and click "make my profile public" - the change will be instant (no need to click save button) and everyone will see your custom URL. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks! that was it!

Comment: Cody, can you please edit the answer to reflect the changes?