# How do I qualify for Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

I tried "qualifying" through stack overflow and got this:

> We had a look at your Stack Overflow activity but it didn’t quite meet our threshold just yet.

No surprise, I guess. I know my SO rep is low, but is there more to it than that? What is the criteria to qualify for the careers site?

Comment: You could always just complete the survey...

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly enough, the answer to your question is a secret!

It's based on expertise in a tag and activity on the site, but that's about as far as we know.

David Fullerton [posted this on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81703/276203):

> The exact criteria probably won't be announced, because we don't want people to game it. It's not a straight "greater than X reputation", but based on expertise in a tag, and your recent activity on the site.

You can also get invited by going to [this page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one) and clicking the "Request an Invitation" button.